# How is the `type` keyword implemented in Scala

Tags: scala, types, dependency-injection

Is `type` in scala just a syntactic sugar that acts like a macro during compile time, or is there some other magic involved? In a situation like this:

```
type Bar1 = Foo
type Bar2 = Foo
val bar1 = injector.getInstance(classOf[Bar1])
val bar2 = injector.getInstance(classOf[Bar2])
```

Would the DI container be able to distinguish between the two 'type aliases' ?

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question. In your title, you ask how it is *implemented*, i.e. about its *pragmatics*. But in the question body, you ask how it is *specificied* to behave, i.e. about its *semantics*. Which one are you interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar that assigns a different name to the same type. The compiler does not generate a new type so is not able to distinguish type aliases of the same type from each other, or from the original type. So for example:

```
type Foo = String
def foo(f:Foo)
val s : String = "bar"
foo(s)
```

would compile just fine.

In the same way, a DI container would be unable to distinguish the two cases you've shown at runtime because there were never two distinct types at compile time.

Comment: This is wrong, see the last example in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#type-equality. I.e. the compiler _does_ generate separate types, they are just normalized at a specific stage.

Comment: type Foo = String => defined type alias Foo
classOf[Foo] => res0: Class[Foo] = class java.lang.String

Comment: so it may be that deep in the compiler it generates a separate type, but for all practical purposes the alias is indistinguishable from the original type. It would be interesting to see the generated bytecode, but I suspect there is nothing that would allow the alias to be detected at runtime.

Comment: "for all practical purposes the alias is indistinguishable from the original type" As long as you don't use Scala reflection (not Java reflection, such as `classOf`), yes. But once you do, they _are_ distinguishable. And one of the basic uses of Scala reflection is precisely to make information about Scala-level types available at runtime with `TypeTag`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you use Java reflection and `classOf` to distinguish two type aliases?

Comment: @IulianDragos: You can't. Java reflection doesn't know anything about Scala features such as Type Aliases. You have to use Scala reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a DI container using Scala reflection and macros *could* distinguish them (though `classOf` doesn't make sense in this case), but probably shouldn't: it would violate principle of least surprise rather strongly. Rather more usefully, it can distinguish `List[Apple]` and `List[Orange]` despite their `classOf` being the same.